# How to get mapping of browser and native host launched through extension launched from an application?

Tags: chromium, chrome-native-messaging

Suppose an application launches a browser which in turn launches a native messaging host through an extension. After that, say, application needs to communicate with the native host which in turn can talk to the browser. I have a couple of questions on this

1. What is the best way to achieve this?
2. If the application ends up launching multiple browsers, how does application know to communicate with the right host program to send information to the right browser?

~ Nathan

Comment: You can use IPC (inter process communication) to talk between two apps. In Chromium, until and unless multiple profiles are not executed, multiple browser windows will not launch multiple native messaging hosts. You will have to execute another profile to execute multiple native messaging hosts as it's tied to profiles

Comment: Each browser instance will launch its own Native Messaging host. Just keep track of the browsers launched.